# Remove or shorten WAV playback delay in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, wav

I have a code that allows for a set of wav files in succession i.e to play one after the other . There is a short delay between the playback of each wav file .

here is the code i use to instantiate the playback

```
 My.Computer.Audio.Play((ttsdic.Item(key)), AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

`(ttsdic.Item.(Key))` is the `value` of some `strings` as `wav` files in a `dictionary` .

the main issue here is the delay between playback due to the fact that that the `AudioPlayMode` is `WaitToComplete`

is there a way to "join" each wav file which is basically removing the delay between playback for each successive wav file

Comment: Could it be a moment of silence at the end of each file that's part of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AudioPlayMode.Background` or use an `array` for *wav* files and the use a *for loop*

Comment: i am using a for loop and i had used AudioPlayMode.Background.

there seems to be a good code here but i do not know how to incorporate it into my code. 

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?714827-RESOLVED-Concatenate-wav-files-via-byte-array

Comment: that one is concatenating the two files whereas you want to play the two one by one without gap. right?

Comment: or may be there is some blank gap at the end or starting of the 'wav' file. Try to cut that blank part using a 'mp3' editor

Comment: i cut out the blank parts in FL studio . 
i want to connect the wav files during successive playback . so your correct , i want to play them 1 by one without the gap

Comment: Now use your method to play it. It will work. Mark the up if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Might be a delay needed for loading the WAV file from disc. 
Try to preload them into streams, and let Play play from stream in memory. You could probably put the streams into a dictionary and iterate through that like you already do with the paths.

Comment: actualliy i will be "compressing" all wav files to 1 wav file then play it